# Airflow SQSSensor message filtering

Tags: airflow

Given below json:

```
{ "Model" : "level1" }
```

what is the right combination of `message_filtering_match_values` and `message_filtering_config` values? I try below but it fails:

```
model_operator = SQSSensor(
  task_id='model_operator',
  dag=dag,
  sqs_queue='https://sqs.somewhere/somequeue.fifo',
  aws_conn_id='aws_default',
  message_filtering='jsonpath',
  message_filtering_config='Model[*]',
  message_filtering_match_values=['level1'],
  mode='reschedule')
```

Error message is:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/test_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 94, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 414, in __init__
    "arguments were:\n**kwargs: {k}".format(c=self.__class__.__name__, k=kwargs, t=task_id),
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to SQSSensor (task_id: model_operator). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'message_filtering': 'jsonpath', 'message_filtering_config': 'Model[*]', 'message_filtering_match_values': ['level1']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `message_filtering` / `message_filtering_config` / `message_filtering_match_values` were added recently in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16904) it was released in [Amazon provider version 2.2.0](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/commits.html#id1)
From the traceback we can see that these parameters are not recognized by the operator which means that you are running an older version of the Amazon provider.

You should upgrade the Amazon provider to the latest version.

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon --upgrade
```

It's also recommended to read the documentation about [constraint](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation.html) files.

You didn't mention what Airflow version you are running nor what version of the Amazon provider so note to read the change logs in case you are upgrading major version.

Comment: thanks @Elad I'm using AWS MWAA which is on v2.0.2. I'm not sure which version of providers are there (v1.3.0 I assume) and I have no idea how to upgrade in aws env

Comment: @alital you did not mention in the question that you are using MWAA. For now MWAA supports only Airflow 2.0.2 so the updated version of the provider will not work for you as it needs at least Airflow 2.1.0 - Contact AWS support for instructions. You can always create a custom version of Sensor by backporting the PR to your Airflow version.